# List Mule Apps and their IP addresses

Tags: mulesoft, cloudhub

Is there a way to list all the Mule applications deployed in a VPC in Cloudhub, and their private IP addresses as a report (maybe in Monitoring)? I know the private IP addresses are dynamic and will change, but is there a way to get such a report?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do that however you can gather the information together with a script or application. I can give you the high level direction. You need to [get the list of applications](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-get-a-list-of-applications-via-Anypoint-Platform-APIs) for each environment associated with the VPC, get the deployment region to confirm that it matches the VPC region (just in case that multi region deployments are enabled) and the status to ensure it is running. You can use CloudHub 1.0 REST API: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/cloudhub-api/minor/1.0/pages/home/

Then with the resulting list of applications you can query the [DNS names used by CloudHub 1.0](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-networking-guide#dns-records):

- mule-worker-myapp.region.cloudhub.io to get the public IPs
- mule-worker-internal-myapp.region.cloudhub.io to get the internal IP inside the VPC